# SQL IF EXISTS behavior weird

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was changing some stored procedure and something weird happened.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1
           WHERE varID = (CAST(@v_varID AS int) + 1))
    UPDATE TABLE2
    SET id = (CAST(@v_varID AS int) + 1) 
    WHERE category = @v_category 
ELSE
    UPDATE CATEGORY 
    SET id = (CAST(@v_varID AS int) + 1) 
    WHERE category = @v_category
```

This was my code. Because `@v_varID` is of type `varchar`, I needed to convert it to `int` in order to increment `id`. The problem was when `@v_varID` is an converted, it get caught at `IF EXISTS`. When I just update it without `EXISTS` it works just as I expected.

`ERROR_LOG` shows another non-convertible `@v_varID` in the table cannot convert to int. I have been passing just `'800'` or some varchar-ed integer so it should work but somehow it doesn't pass `IF EXISTS` (It does update if I get rid of `IF EXISTS`). I just used another way to make it work but I am curious why.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the datatype of `varID` in `table1`?

Comment: @ZLK All ids are varchar(50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update`s both have the condition `category = @v_category`.

Your `if exists ()` subquery does not.

I am guessing that `varid` is a string.  The comparison to an integer converts the `varid` to an integer.

Further, I guess that the category is being checked before the conversion.  In other words, there is a row with a bad `v_varid` value (i.e. cannot be converted to an integer) and this is on a row where the categories do not match.

Comment: It was because I was comparing `varID` which is `varchar` to an integer. I had no idea I couldn't do that because in my experience so far SQL pretty much handled by itself. Thanks!

Comment: @MinLee, SQL Server will implicitly convert unlike data types according to strict [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). You are right SQL Server will handle the conversion but you'll get an error in cases where the conversion can't be done. That can be plan-dependent so it's an accident waiting to happen, which is one reason why explicitly matching data types is a best practice.